# ST (Terminal from Suckless) does not appear in "search" plasma

Tags: arch-linux, plasma

I cloned the repo with 
`git clone git://git.suckless.org/st`

Next I did did

```
cd st
sudo make clean install
```

And then I run it with `./st`. It works, but the problem is that it dose not appear in "Search" in plasma.

For example xterm appears in search, but st does not.

[image: successfully searching for xterm, in plasma search]

[image: failing to find st, in plasma search]

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor thx btw.

Comment: If you never groked apostrophes then see my article https://ctrlaltdelor.wordpress.com/2014/01/09/a-single-rule-for-apostrophes/ I was trying to learn them a few years back, when I suddenly realised that they were easier than the teacher's explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you manually installed it. You will have to manually add it to plasma.

- Right click the launcher
- Select `edit applications ...`
- Chose a category and add it.

It should now appear in the search.

---

This only does if for the one user. There will be a global config file somewhere, if all user need it.